# Bootstrap Affix Content scrolls to far up on screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I use the basic Bootstrap Affix method to scroll to sections when clicking on a list group item.

This all works well.

The issue is, the content's title (anchor) disappears behind the header section of my pages

With fixed Top Navigation, it disappears behind the Menu, if the Top navigation is not fixed, but The WP Admin Toolbar is visible (logged in user), it disappears behind the Admin Toolbar.

Is there any way to set a kind of "Top Margin" for the title (anchor), so it will not scroll that far up?

To xplain better see this screenshots:
[BEFORE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l2jjl765xarv6zi/BEFORE.png?dl=0)
[AFTER](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k15bav8saztks4/AFTER%20CLICK%20%3A%20SCROLL.png?dl=0)

I do not use JS but use just simple HTML for it.

Here the Mockup:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
            <!--Affix start-->
            <div data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#section-1" class="list-group-item active">Section I</a>
                    <a href="#section-2" class="list-group-item">Section II</a>
                    <a href="#section-3" class="list-group-item">Section III</a>
                    <a href="#section-4" class="list-group-item">Section IV</a>
                    <a href="#section-5" class="list-group-item">Section V</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Affix end-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <!--Content start-->
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="section-2" class="section">
                    <h3>Section I</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>               
                </div>
                <div id="section-3" class="section">
                    <h3>Section II</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>                
                </div>
                <div id="section-4" class="section">
                    <h3>Section III</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p> 
                </div>
                <div id="section-5" class="section">
                    <h3>Section IV</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p> 
                </div>
                <div id="section-6" class="section">
                    <h3>Section V</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p> 
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Content end-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have also tried to play with data-offset-top, but that is not even influencing the content, it is intended for the List (where you click to scroll-to)

Anybody has a idea why this is happening and how I could have the "Title" of post (my actual anchors) as the "upper limit" so that "titles" won't disappear behind the Menu/Admin bar?

Appreciated...

This solutions I already tried:
Not working, completely out of scope (padding to body won't solve anything here)
[Bootstrap affix issues with sticky top navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23621495/bootstrap-affix-issues-with-sticky-top-navigation)
CSS solution that will break the scroll experience and is not working in my case, I did not try yet the JS solution...
[Div anchors scrolling too far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11501025/div-anchors-scrolling-too-far)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to combine positive `padding-top` and the same negative `margin-top` for `.section`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#nav").affix();
});
```

```css
.section {
  padding-top: 26px;
  margin-top: -26px;
}
.section:first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}
#nav {
  width: 170px;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 hidden-xs">
            <!--Affix start-->
            <div id="nav" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="0">
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#section-1" class="list-group-item active">Section I</a>
                    <a href="#section-2" class="list-group-item">Section II</a>
                    <a href="#section-3" class="list-group-item">Section III</a>
                    <a href="#section-4" class="list-group-item">Section IV</a>
                    <a href="#section-5" class="list-group-item">Section V</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Affix end-->
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <!--Content start-->
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div id="section-1" class="section">
                    <h3>Section I</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>          
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>               
                </div>
                <div id="section-2" class="section">
                    <h3>Section II</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>          
                    <p>...</p>                
                </div>
                <div id="section-3" class="section">
                    <h3>Section III</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p> 
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>          
                </div>
                <div id="section-4" class="section">
                    <h3>Section IV</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p> 
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>          
                </div>
                <div id="section-5" class="section">
                    <h3>Section V</h3>
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p> 
                    <p>...</p>
                    <p>...</p>          
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Content end-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: works, at least tested with non-fixed navbar. Cool, thanks a lot.
bootstrap could freely add some more description to their components site :).

Comment: If you fell like, :D , perhaps you also have a idea how to add a "event" so the currently viewed section will be highlighted in the affix?
I saw that too on bootstrap site, but they don't explain how. 
Once they say, you need the scroll spy, but there you can't use fixed. and affix uses fixed in CSS

Comment: @DanielLestrange you can add handler on scroll event on document and compare `scrollTop` with `offset.top` of each section. Besides you can cache `offset.top`s to increase performance. However you must recalc cached values on `window.resize`.

Comment: Thanks. I solved :) this part too ;) (anyway wasn't related to this Stack